# Angular service not executed in the same order

Tags: .net, angular, typescript

**Typescript Code**

```
 SaveEmployee() {
        let employeeAge= 0;
        employeeAge = GetAge();
        if(employeeAge >18) {
          //some logic Code comes here
        } else {
          //some other logic Code comes here
      }
    }

    GetAge() {
     let age= 0;
     this.employeeService.getAge(this.employeeId).subscribe(data => {
            age= data; });
     return age;    
    }
```

I am updating an employee with age condition using angular typescript code. Here the GetAge() method returns always 0. The SaveEmployee() method is executed prior to the age calculation. Please help me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

IT won't. Because `employeeService.getAge(...)` would return the response asynchronously. To fix that, do this:

```
async SaveEmployee() {
  let employeeAge = 0;
  employeeAge = await GetAge();
  if (employeeAge > 18) {
    //some logic Code comes here
  } else {
    //some other logic Code comes here
  }
}

async GetAge() {
  let age = 0;
  const age = await this.employeeService.getAge(this.employeeId).toPromise();
  return age;
}
```

Here we're using the latest ES2018 `async` `await` syntax that works with promises.

I've instead of `subscribe`ing to the `Observable` that is returned by `employeeService.getAge(...)`, converted it into a Promise by using `toPromise()`

Then I can use await on it and then do the needful.

Answer (score 0):

Your async method will be running in a different thread - So i think you wont get the age before the subscribe completes and rest of the code doesn't wait - you can move the logic inside you subscribe like this

```
this.employeeService.getAge(this.employeeId).subscribe((data) => {

     if(data >18) {
      //some logic Code comes here
     } else {
      //some other logic Code comes here
     }
});
```

Hope that works - happy coding :)

**Update:**

You can use `promise` to get the data try something like this

```
GetAge() {
    return new Promise(res => { 
        this.employeeService.getAge(this.employeeId).subscribe(data => {
            res(data);
           });
      });
   }
```

While reading the data from the promise

```
SaveEmployee() {
     let employeeAge= 0;
     this.GetAge().then((res) => {
     if(res >18) {
          //some logic Code comes here
      } else {
          //some other logic Code comes here
      }
   });
 }
```

Otherwise you can send the data to another function and process the logic there I'm not sure that's the right way because you end up in creating a method that is dependable only for the function

```
GetAge() {
    this.employeeService.getAge(this.employeeId).subscribe(data => {
         SomeMethod(data);
       });
     }
```

I think promise might help you - Happy coding :)

Comment: Yes, but how to resolve the issue if we proceed with the way mentioned in this Question?

Answer (score 0):

The http post or http get service call will work asynchronously.

You can write second write code like below:

```
SaveEmployee() {
            let employeeAge= 0;
         this.employeeService.getAge(this.employeeId).subscribe(data => {
                employeeAge= data;
                if(employeeAge >18) {
              //some logic Code comes here
            } else {
              //some other logic Code comes here
          }
                 }); 

        }
```